# Write data to MS Access using VB6

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2010

This is my first VB6 application. My problem is there is no helpful example of writing data (including current date & time) from a form to an Access database. Here's my code based on all my research from different websites.

If you can't understand my code or if it is wrong, please show me a working example.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim conConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmdCommand As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rstRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim logInId As Integer
    Dim guardId As String
    Dim studentId As String
    Dim laptopName As String
    Dim laptopBrand As String
    Dim logInDate As Date
    Dim logInTime As Date

    guardId = Text2.Text
    studentId = Text3.Text
    laptopName = Text4.Text
    laptopBrand = Text5.Text
    logInDate = DateVal(Now)
    logInTime = TimeVal(Now)

    conConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        App.Path & "\" & "Database.accdb;Mode=Read|Write"
    conConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    conConnection.Open

    rstRecordSet.Open "laptopLoggedInLoggedOutInfo", conConnection
    logInId = rstRecordSet.RecordCount

    With cmdCommand
        .ActiveConnection = conConnection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        'f means field
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO laptopLoggedInLoggedOutInfo(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) "

        .Prepared = True
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f1", adInteger, adParamInput, , logInId + 1)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f2", adChar, adParamInput, 20, guardId)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f3", adChar, adParamInput, 20, studentId)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f4", adChar, adParamInput, 20, laptopName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f5", adChar, adParamInput, 20, laptopBrand)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f6", adDate, adParamInput, , logInDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f7", adDate, adParamInput, , logInTime)

        Set rstRecordSet = cmdCommand.Execute
    End With

    conConnection.Close

    Set conConnection = Nothing
    Set cmdCommand = Nothing
    Set rstRecordSet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

I've made in-line comments on your code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
```

Whilst this doesn't matter for this particular example, generally don't declare object variables "As New". It is better if you instantiate them manually. Essentially, "As New" declared variables are checked every time you try to use a property or method on them, and if the variable `Is Nothing`, it creates a new instance. This may not necessarily be what you intend.

```
    Dim conConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmdCommand As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rstRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim logInId As Integer
    Dim guardId As String
    Dim studentId As String
    Dim laptopName As String
    Dim laptopBrand As String
    Dim logInDate As Date
    Dim logInTime As Date

    guardId = Text2.Text
    studentId = Text3.Text
    laptopName = Text4.Text
    laptopBrand = Text5.Text
    logInDate = DateVal(Now)
    logInTime = TimeVal(Now)
```

Make sure that the Data Source substring is points to your Access database.

```
    conConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        App.Path & "\" & "Database.accdb;Mode=Read|Write"
    conConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    conConnection.Open
```

I see that you are using a recordset just to receive a count of records in `logInId`. I really wouldn't use this as an ID. If you delete records from the table, then your ID will become smaller. Generally, if you want a unique ID, you must ensure that the ID *always* increments.

```
    rstRecordSet.Open "laptopLoggedInLoggedOutInfo", conConnection
    logInId = rstRecordSet.RecordCount
```

My suggestion: use "SELECT MAX(f1) FROM laptopLoggedInLoggedOutInfo", and retrieve the first value, ensuring that if the value is null, it returns zero, e.g.

`rstRecordSet.Open "SELECT MAX(logInId) FROM laptopLoggedInLoggedOutInfo", conConnection`
`logInId = IIf(IsNull(rstRecordSet.Fields(0)), 0, IsNull(rstRecordSet.Fields(0)))`

```
    With cmdCommand
        .ActiveConnection = conConnection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        'f means field
```

Are these *really* your fieldnames: f1, f2, f2, etc.? I would be surprised. Replace them with the correct field names.

```
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO laptopLoggedInLoggedOutInfo(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) "
```

Note that the actual parameter names, e.g. f1,f2,f3, etc. seem not to matter. It is the order in the INSERT statement that matters.

```
        .Prepared = True
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f1", adInteger, adParamInput, , logInId + 1)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f2", adChar, adParamInput, 20, guardId)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f3", adChar, adParamInput, 20, studentId)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f4", adChar, adParamInput, 20, laptopName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f5", adChar, adParamInput, 20, laptopBrand)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f6", adDate, adParamInput, , logInDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("f7", adDate, adParamInput, , logInTime)
```

Don't use a return value in use the following line. And INSERT statement returns no values:

```
        Set rstRecordSet = cmdCommand.Execute
```

Do this instead:

```
        cmdCommand.Execute

    End With

    conConnection.Close
```

You probably don't need to set these variables to Nothing - VB does it for you, anyway. However, if you do, it is generally good practice to do this in reverse order of creation.

```
    Set conConnection = Nothing
    Set cmdCommand = Nothing
    Set rstRecordSet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't much advantage in using ACE formats, you only limit portability.  MDBs are almost always a better idea.

You also have a ton of code there for something this minimal.  And don't forget to escape the DB path, you can use apostrophes or quotes in the connection string.

Make your "f1" field type IDENTITY ("autonumber").

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cm As ADODB.Command

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" _
          & App.Path & "\Database.accdb';Mode=Read|Write"
    Set cm = New ADODB.Command
    With cm
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        'Assume "f1" is type IDENTITY ("Autonumber").
        .CommandText = _
                "INSERT INTO laptopLoggedInLoggedOutInfo(f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7) " _
              & "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        Set .ActiveConnection = cn
        'Seriously?  Give those TextBoxes names!
        .Execute , _
                 Array(Text2.Text, Text3.Text, Text4.Text, Text5.Text, Date, Time()), _
                 adExecuteNoRecords
    End With
End Sub
```